# Automatically deploy to opswork on Gitlab CI successful build?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, aws-opsworks, gitlab-ci

I have successfully setup gitlab and gitlab CI however I have one issue,

With travis-ci you can have it automatically deploy to aws opsworks upon a successful build - I can't work out any way to do this through gitlab-ci - infact I cannot work out any way to trigger **any** action on a successful build?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this with the following steps:

1. push something to the Git repo;
2. Travis CI will run all tests;
3. Travis CI will zip all necessary files in the kind of package;
4. Travis CI will deploy/upload this zip file to the AWS S3 bucket;
5. Travis CI will trigger deployment of the AWS OpsWorks;
6. OpsWorks will take this ZIP file and deploy it to the configured application (to all instances);
7. Travis CI will notify you about succesful deploy (via email/slack chat/snap chat/whatever).

[More details you can find here](http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2014/12/28/amazon-deploy-to-aws-opsworks-via-travis/)

Comment: the question is about gitlab CI, and all you talk about is Travis? wut.

Answer (score -3):

Just add the actions to your build script.